# Default.png file is not being loaded on device

Tags: iphone

I am trying to display Default.png image when application starts. So user wont have to see that black screen. But the problem is its working fine on simulator but on device its not being loaded and black screen is being shown before app loads.

What could be problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

first delete your app from the device.
then when your app open on the xcode press on the upper bar product -> clean
make sure the image are name "Default.png"
run on your device! :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it not show the Default.png at all, or just after a short period of time ?

Not at all: Try setting a new Default.png in the Organizer

After short time: When hitting build and run your app needs some time to start up, because the debugger is linking itself to your app, this causes a delay of a couple of seconds where your default.png is not displayed.

Comment: Sorry to ask you this question but How can we set Deafult.png from the organiser? I just added default.png in resource folder. Isnt that right way?

Comment: Usually that way works. 

Go to the organizer and select your iPhone. There you can take a screenshot and set that one as default.png.

Comment: Is there any limit on default.png file size? mine is 67 kb I guess.

Comment: actually i don't know if there is an actual limit, but it should be 320 x 480 Pixels.